# Add a column in Registration Table

Tags: oracle, ddl, alter

Refer the following schema and add a field – DOC with Date type to the Registration table.

Ensure DOC greater than DOJ. (Note : DOC - Date of Completion ).

This is the schema.

[image: course enrollement management]

This is my code

```
alter table registration add doc date
  add constraint registration_chk_date check(doc>doj);
```

when i compile and run my above code, giving me result table altered but from above code my testcases are not passing at all. Can anybody tell where I went wrong?

Below are testcases i am getting after evaluating my above code.

Test case 1 - Column name and datatype check

Check the datatype(s) for the column(s)

```
Table
COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
COURSEID
DOC
DOJ
```

Test case 2 - Column constraint check

Check the constraint(s) for the column(s)

```
COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
COURSEID
DOC
DOJ
STUDID
```

Test case 3 - Column constraint name check
Check the constraint(s) name for the column(s)

```
COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
COURSEID
DOC
DOJ
STUDID
```

Comment: Which test cases are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you are using constraints other than PK and FK but observe the last row in the result.
Null values are allowed in DOJ and it may cause your test cases to fail.

```
CREATE TABLE registration(
    courseid   NUMBER(4),
    studid     NUMBER(4),
    doj        DATE
)
/

    INSERT INTO registration VALUES(
        1001,
        100,
        sysdate
    );
/

ALTER TABLE registration ADD doc DATE;

ALTER TABLE registration ADD CONSTRAINT registration_chk_date CHECK(doc > doj);

INSERT INTO registration VALUES(
    1001,
    100,
    sysdate + 1,
    sysdate + 1
);

INSERT INTO registration VALUES(
    1001,
    100,
    sysdate,
    sysdate + 1
);

INSERT INTO registration(
    courseid,
    studid,
    doc
)VALUES(
    1002,
    101,
    sysdate
);

SELECT *
FROM registration;
```

[image]